# How long can musicians perform before they get tired?

Tags: piano, voice, violin, performing

I'm conceiving a story where this might come up. How long can musicians perform before performance drops? There are hard limits imposed by biological needs (e.g. having to go to the toilet), but I'm wondering if those are the actual limits or do musicians get tired long before those biological limits are reached.

If it varies by instrument (I imagine it does) I'm most interested in singing, the piano & violin.

---

For example I could say a character wakes up sad one day but knows music cheers him up, so he takes out the instruments and plays until he gets tired, and the question would be how much time has passed before the next scene occurs. I don't need a very precise answer; I only need to know if I should write "2 hours passed" or "30 minutes passed" or something.

Comment: This is too broad, even with the instruments restricted, to be answered in the general form you've asked it. Is there a motivation behind the question that might allow for a more specific answer?

Comment: As a brief illustration: the current world record for a 100-mile runner is 11h:14m:56s, and the current world record for 100 meters is 9:58 seconds. 100 miles is approximately 161,000 meters, and the 100 meter record is roughly 10 seconds. Expanding the 100 meter record to 100 miles would give a (approximate) time of 16,100sec ~ 4.5h. So the endurance test depends on speed and distance. This is true as well for music: how physically and emotionally demanding is the music? Are there rest intervals, and for how long? How long does the music last? ....

Comment: @Aaron I'm conceiving a story, and the story would vary depending on the answer, but it wouldn't be drastic. For example I could say a character wakes up sad one day but knows music cheers him up, so he takes out the instruments and plays until he gets tired, and the question would be how much time has passed before the next scene occurs. I don't need a very precise answer; I only need to know if I should write "2 hours passed" or "30 minutes passed" or something.

Comment: How long can a runner run? Depends on if they trained to be a sprinter or a marathon runner. Or if they haven’t trained much lately. It’s kind of the same for musicians.

Comment: @ToddWilcox well, I would say the average human cannot run for 10 minutes without stopping. Fit people can, and certainly Olympic marathon runners can run for much longer than 10 minutes, but not the average person.

Comment: I have to agree with @Aaron, that's really broad and very opinion-based. There are accounts of some Guinnes records for long lasting musical performances, but I doubt you should consider those for a "realistic" story. Most musicians couldn't stand for more than 3-4 hours.

Comment: I tried to write up an answer just now, and even understanding your goals, there are just too many variables. Here's a suggestion: pick an instrument and listen to music written for that instrument. Choose pieces you imagine your character playing in this situation and then see the total time involved in those pieces. Alternatively, listen to some concert recordings and see how much (timewise) of the program you can imagine your character getting through.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although there is a music tie-in, this is really a question about how to develop a literary character; the musical aspect is secondary, at least until the character is more clearly defined.

Comment: I am a guitarist who pokes around on keyboard and violin. As long as I'm maintaining decent form on guitar, not fretting too hard or getting into bad positions, I will get bored with my playing LONG before performance (ability to fret or strum) lessens. In long practices or performances, I personally get a pain between my shoulder blades, but playing while sitting eases that. With good form, you should be able to go for hours on most instruments.

Comment: @DaveJacoby tell that to musicians playing Wagner at Bayreuth Festival ;-)

Comment: I take all this to mean I can write a musician "played for hours" while remaining within the realm of possibility. That's good enough for my purposes, thanks!

Comment: I once played a gig with 'revolving singers' & occasional line-up changes, but an unchanging core personnel, that ran for 12 hours… and that's being "on it", in performance mode, not just sitting tootling on an acoustic in the bedroom. I wouldn't like to do it every day, but it shows it can be done.

Comment: I have played music from I woke up until I went to bed, with some pauses for food and taking a walk maybe. So you probably need to write if you allow/disallow pauses. Something like 16 hours maybe? If you allow your character to play under threat it would probably be much higher. I always wrap up when my hands start aching though, perhaps I finish the song and then quit for the day.

Comment: I suggest 'some time later' - and if well written, will be in the imagination of the reader - like any good storyline.

Comment: @musicamante - not my field of expertise, but I understand from talking to experienced 'pit' players that such as the Ring is done in shifts… with the brass section being first in the pub & last to return  ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin shhh, don't tell anyone that, let's make people believe brass and percussions always stay there for the whole duration, so that nobody can accuse us about those empty kegs ;-) (btw, there are not "shifts", at least not for the same Opera if performed in the same day(s), but we do have longer breaks)

Comment: It depends on what you consider a performance drop as well as the training level of the musician.  Think about the average concert.  1-2 hours.  A rock band will be running all over the stage.  A classical orchestra might play 4 hours with a break.  There are contests for playing endurance, look up the world record.  If this is for a story why does it matter?

Comment: @Allure The average person probably can’t play piano for more than ten minutes either. Not sure what your point is. My point is that the answer depends entirely on how the musician has trained and on the music being played and the instrument. Even professional brass players can’t keep blowing fortissimo for too long because their lips wear out, but cellists can bow aggressively for longer, although not as long as a whole symphony. It just depends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could say a character wakes up sad one day but knows music cheers him up, so he takes out the instruments and plays until he gets tired, and the question would be how much time has passed before the next scene occurs

The answer is another question: "How long is a piece of string?"

To make it clear let me change the subject in your question from playing an instrument to running -

> I could say a character wakes up sad one day but knows running cheers him up, so he puts on his running shorts and shoes and runs until he gets tired, and the question would be how much time has passed before the next scene occurs

Posed that way it is very clear that it depends on the person. There are actually [6 day races](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-day_race) in which competitors run for 6 days with breaks for eating, drinking and the toilet. Whoever runs furthest in the 6 days wins. A select few people are capable of taking part. At the other extreme there are people who struggle to run for a bus. Or, if you prefer to limit it to professional runners, there are sprinters like Usain Bolt who have to stop after less than 400m. The same is true for musicians.

Obviously the ultra-marathoners don't start with 6 day races or even marathons. They start with much shorter runs and build up. Doing otherwise would lead to immediate injury. The same is true with playing an instrument. If you start off by trying to play for 12 hours you will quickly get injured.

However, as famous violin teacher Leopold Auer used to say "If you are serious, practice three hours a day; four if you are a little stupid." (see Mary Ellen Goree's comment in [this thread](https://www.violinist.com/discussion/thread.cfm?page=749)).

Answer (score 2):

It varies from person to person.  Factors are health, environment, ergonomics, technique, diet, sleep . . .

A pianist with an ergonomic technique will not tire because gravity does all the work.  All they need is proper alignment and they can endure for a long time. Gravity will keep them relaxed. It is called resting up.

I once played two fourteen hour cattle call auditions for a B'way show.  The first day was effortless but I didn't get much sleep that night and was dragging the second day but my arms gave me no problem. I'm sure I did but don't recall taking any bathroom breaks.  I cut down on liquids on purpose.  I played another three day cattle call but singers were spaced out in half hour increments.  After accompanying someone for one minute I reclined in a theater seat. These three days were more exhausting because when I sat in the theater seat I slouched and leaned back causing gravity to pull down on my neck and back.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to vary quite a bit, and depend mostly on two variables: individual stamina and the method of sound production.

I'm primarily a guitarist.  If I've been playing for five hours and I have to play a song that has a very high note, fatigue isn't really going to hinder me.  But the trumpet player on the same gig may struggle, as he or she has been using smaller muscles, and needs to really work that very tired embouchure to hit the pitch.